Sublime Text 4 - Auto-Update fails (Win11 Pro)
I have a strange problem using Sublime Text 4. I run the editor on 2 systems. Both on Win 11 Pro. Both versions with the same plugins.
The Software does regular checks on startup for updates.
On System 1 the updates do as intended. The dialog starts, I click update and install it and I am done.
On System 2, when installing the update from the dialog window, it tries to and then stops with the error ("Unable to rename C:\Program Files\Sublime Text to C:\Program Files\Sublime Text (4169), it is being used by another process"):

There is no other process than Sublime using sublime. And since it works on my other system, I wonder what could be different on this system, so that it breaks and how to repair it.
I can install this manually but then I must do the whole package setup again and its simply annoying. I would prefer to run it the way it is intended to be.

This happens if Sublime or something it launched is still running, which causes Windows to lock the folder. This could be for example the plugin host remaining running because a package has launched a task. In any event, downloading the full installer and installing over top of the existing Sublime doesn't require you to reconfigure anything; all of your configuration is kept separate from the installation location specifically for this reason.
